# Move constructor should be called by default

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

In following case where i have created move ctor in Integer class, i am expecting that it should be called by default on rvalue reference while creating Product object but i am getting call of copy constructor only.
Gcc - 7.5.0 on Ubuntu 18

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Integer 
{
    int *dInt = nullptr;
public: 
    Integer(int xInt)  {
        dInt = new int(xInt);
        cout<<"Integer Created"<<endl;
    } 
    Integer(const Integer &xObj)
    {
        cout<<"Copy called"<<endl;
        dInt = new int(xObj.mGetInt());
    }

    Integer(Integer &&xObj)
    {
        cout<<"Move called"<<endl;
        dInt = xObj.dInt;
        xObj.dInt = nullptr;
    }

    Integer& operator=(const Integer &xObj)
    {
        cout<<"Assignment operator called"<<endl;
        *dInt = xObj.mGetInt();
        return *this;
    }

    Integer& operator=(Integer &&xObj)
    {
        cout<<"Move Assignment operator called"<<endl;
        delete dInt;
        dInt = xObj.dInt;
        xObj.dInt = nullptr;
        return *this;   
    }
    ~Integer() 
    {
        cout<<"Integer destroyed"<<endl;
        delete dInt;
    }

    int mGetInt() const {return *dInt;}
};

class Product 
{
    Integer dId;
public: 
    Product(Integer &&xId)
    :dId(xId)
    {

    }
};
int main () 
{
    Product P(10); // Notice implicit conversion of 10 to Integer obj.
}
```

In above case, move called if i use dId(std::move(xId)) in  Product class ctor, I was expecting it should called by default on rvalue reference.
In following case i couldn't avoid creating of temporary object of Integer class, Is there any good way to avoid creating of temporary object.

```
    Product(const Integer &xId)
    :dId(xId)
    {

    }
    
    Product(10); // inside main
```

My purpose of above question to build my understanding so that i can utilize temporary object memory better.

Comment: Side note: Your class doesn't seem to need an `int*`. Consider just using an `int` member, or perhaps, a `std::optional<int>`, if you need to track that there is no int whatsoever (which you do now with a `nullptr`).

Comment: This was to build my understanding around move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need `std::move` to "propagate" rvalue-reference-ness.**

Inside the body of the following function:

```
void foo(int&& x);
```

…an expression `x` is an lvalue `int`. **Not** `int&&`.

**References don't really "exist"** — even though they are powered by the type system, they are supposed to be treated as aliases (rather than separate entities), so using `x` inside `foo` is treated just like using the original, referred-to `int` inside `foo` … and doing that would *also* create a copy, as you know.

---

This will do the job:

```
Product(Integer&& xId)
    : dId(std::move(xId))
{}
```

However, I actually encourage you to take `Integer` by value:

```
Product(Integer xId)
    : dId(std::move(xId))
{}
```

That way, you can use the same constructor for passing lvalue `Integer` too, and a copy will be produced *if necessary*, whereas a move will happen automatically if not (e.g. by passing in a literal, which will automatically trigger selection of `Integer`'s move constructor).